# FFmpeg segmentation causes audible pop in output

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm attempting to segment an audio file into 15 second slices. This can be done using something akin to the below command:

```
ffmpeg -i example.mp3 -f segment -segment_time 15 -c copy out%03d.mp3
```

However, doing this causes an audible "pop" in resulting output files. It only happens immediately at the beginning - the rest of the file is fine.

I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845977/how-can-i-encode-and-segment-audio-files-without-having-gaps-or-audio-pops-bet) on StackOverflow that this is caused when transcoding from one lossy format to another, which introduces artifacts. In my situation, I'm dealing with a wide range of formats, and my target output is encoded using a lossy format. Would transcoding from a lossy format into a lossless format, such as WAV, and back to a lossy format prevent this from happening? In this way, I should be dealing with raw PCM information, and I shouldn't get "pops" during segmentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any audio format where each frame can be decoded independently should be fine. Which includes PCM. You could also re-encode to MP3 by dropping the `-c copy`.